# how to make scroll in bootstrap col-md-1

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="well" style="overflow: scroll">
            <div class="col-md-1"> Date </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> Revenue </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> Discounts </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> Items </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> Purchased </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> OV </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> AOV </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> AIO </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> TV </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> UV </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> RPV </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> VCR </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> UCR </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> ATC </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> CCR </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap not scrolling on overflow. instead it is breaking into new line. How do I make it scroll. I want it to scroll in x-axis

Comment: When is it doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed Your Issue

```
div.well {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div.well [class*="col"]{
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/hellosrini/63gnLaq9/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```css
.col{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="well" style="overflow-x: scroll; ">
            <div class="col" style="display: inline-block"> Date </div>
            <div class="col"> Revenue </div>
            <div class="col"> Discounts </div>
            <div class="col"> Items </div>
            <div class="col"> Purchased </div>
            <div class="col"> OV </div>
            <div class="col"> AOV </div>
            <div class="col"> AIO </div>
            <div class="col"> TV </div>
            <div class="col"> UV </div>
            <div class="col"> RPV </div>
            <div class="col"> VCR </div>
            <div class="col"> UCR </div>
            <div class="col"> ATC </div>
            <div class="col"> CCR </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can have grid of maximum 12 columns. So you cannot use col-md-1. You can set its width to fit you available area.

Comment: it is showing scroller in `x-axis` instead, I want it to scroll in `y-axis`

Comment: It is working fine on my screen. You can further check by 'overflow-x: scroll;' or  'overflow-y: scroll;'.

Comment: my head's spinning, I am sorry, I meant i wanted scroller it in x-axis

Comment: I want it to go all in same line, and long with scroller in x-axis bro

Comment: Bootstrap is really designed to prevent horizontal overflow, so this isn't really something you can accomplish with its classes (the entire columned approach is based around floating to the left).